# Not visible NSOpenGLView slows down the whole system

Tags: performance, macos, opengl, nsopenglview

I'm making a Mac OS X (10.8.3) OpenGL application using a NSOpenGLView and the CVDisplayLink to manage the calls to the render method.

The application works fine but when the window gets covered or is in other space (basically when is not visible for some reason) the whole system starts going slow.

I tested and profiled it in several ways and this is what I found:

- The CPU is OK, no CPU consumption increases
- The Memory is fine too, the amount of memory allocated doesn't change
- In the OpenGL Driver Monitor the "CPU Wait for GPU" time increases
- Also does the "CPU Wait for Free OpenGL Command Buffer" (I think this is the problem)
- If no OpenGL draw calls are generated the computer runs fine.

I'm guessing that a non visible NSOpenGLView changes the behavior in some way and it makes my application more GPU consuming.

Any idea of what could be going wrong?